# Accept Any type of argument in cpp

Tags: c++

I want a function that can accept any type of argument and then in the implementation, can check if the type is integer and then can throw a message. For example the function can be called like the following,

```
add(10, 12);
Output : "correct input. addition is 22"
```

```
add(10, "hello")
Output : "wrong input"
```

```
add(10)
Output : "wrong input! missing arguments"
```

Is it possible to achieve this in C++?

Using overloading I will have to create functions of all possible combination such as (int, double), (double, int), (int, string), (string, int) and so on, so is there any other way?

Comment: Can you explain why you don't just define `void add(int, int)` and let the compiler produce the error? C++ is a statically typed language and trying to subvert the type system is an advanced topic. See also [Templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) and [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

Comment: Overloading seems to be one possible solution. Together with templates. But getting a compiler-error seems like a much more saner solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++17, you can use `std::any` and `std::any_cast`:

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>

void add(const std::any& a = "", const std::any& b = "")
{
    try {
        const int ia = std::any_cast<int>(a);
        const int ib = std::any_cast<int>(b);

        std::cout << "correct input. addition is " << ia + ib << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "wrong input" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    add(10, "hello");
    add(10, 12);
    add(10);
    add();
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ZFBNZIE17)

---

A pre-C++17 solution:

```
#include <iostream>

void add(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << "correct input. addition is " << a + b << std::endl;
}

template<typename... Ts>
void add(Ts...)
{
    std::cout << "wrong input" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    add(10, "hello");
    add(10, 12);
    add(10);
    add();
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/kP2MCnSp8)

Comment: To avoid an exception being thrown if you are likely to get one you can also test with `type() ` which returns the typeid of the containing item.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is write an overload that accepts exactly 2 ints:

```
void add(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << "Correct input. Answer is " << a + b << "\n";
}
```

And that should generally be enough. If a call is made with an incorrect number of arguments, or with 2 arguments that can't be converted to `int`, the compiler will produce an error for you.

If you don't want an error, but instead want to print an error message at runtime, you can just add overloads. As you've noticed, adding overloads for explicit types isn't really going to work, but you can add a generic function (a function template) that will accept anything:

```
void add(auto ...) {
    std::cout << "Incorrect input\n";
}
```

Note that pre-C++20, the signature has to be spelled

```
template<typename ...Ts>
void add(Ts ...);
```

You can continue adding more overloads if you want more specific error messages, e.g. for a call where only one argument is passed:

```
void add(auto) {
    std::cout << "Insufficient arguments\n";
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E9vKMG1nY).